# How can I make the monaco editor size to its parent div?

Tags: css, reactjs, monaco-editor

So I am trying to create a layout with two instances of the monaco editor side-by-side.  I'm working with react, and I'm using the [@monaco-edior/react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) component.

I have created the desired layout using a flex layout in CSS:

[image: target]

But when I add the editor component, the layout completely breaks:

[image: actual]

It seems like what is happening is that the monaco editor on the left grows to some intrinsically defined size, and overtakes the layout I have defined in flex.  I'm not sure if this is a CSS issue with how I have written the layout, or it's something I'm missing in terms of configuring the monaco component.

My JSX looks like this:

```
  <div className="container">
      <div className="item">
        <Editor
            onMount={this.editorDidMount}
        ></Editor>
      </div>
      <div className="item">
          <Editor
            onMount={this.editorDidMount}
          ></Editor>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
    background-color: #efefef;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.item + .item {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I'm fairly inexperienced with react and CSS, what might be causing this and where could I start to look to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default width in `monaco-react` is set to 100%, which means it will inherit from parent container.
If you set width to .item class to be 50% then everything should be working as you expect.

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-feather-hkeio?file=/src/App.js) with embeed example

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly!

I'm still not quite sure why though - so by setting the width of .item to 50%, this is saying the contents of .item should be half the size of the parent of .item?

Comment: @sak That's correct